# php link system problem

Tags: php

```
 <?php
 $total=3;
 echo ' 
<div class="idsdiv"><a href="profile.php?id=$total">.$total.</a><div>  ';
 ?>
```

i want to appear $total variable number in the link.why is this script not working?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other problem in your script? what is the problem, show us what you are getting

Comment: In addition to the existing answers: read up on heredoc. That does simplify handling such cases (it's just three lines).

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the whole string with double quotes to embed variables inside:

```
echo "<div class=\"idsdiv\"><a href=\"profile.php?id=$total\">$total</a><div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  $total=3;  
echo "<div class=\"idsdiv\"><a href=\"profile.php?id=$total\">$total</a><div> ";  

?>
```

you had errors with your quotes

Comment: yeah sorry i press tab then space then it auto matically submitted my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotes around your HTML and single quotes around your attributes or do this...

```
echo '<div class="idsdiv"><a href="profile.php?id=' . $total .'">' . $total . '</a><div>  ';
```

PHP doesn't process variable names in strings enclosed in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $total=3;
 echo '<div class="idsdiv"><a href="profile.php?id=',$total,'">',$total,'</a><div>';
 ?>
```

Look at the string section of php.net (http://php.net/string) they talk about how to use each of the types.  One of quote being the ' where nothing is parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You can print HTML without printing it, like so:

```
<?php
  $total = 3;
?>

<div class="idsdiv"><a href="profile.php?id=<?php echo $total; ?>"><?php echo $total; ?></a></div>
```

When I still did PHP, I found it much easier to manage than escaping tons of quotes and things like that.

You can even do it inside of an `if` block too:

```
<?php
  if ($foo == 'bar') {
?>

  <div>Foo is bar</div>

<?php
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method I like is

```
<?php  
     $total=3;  
     echo "<div class='idsdiv'><a href='profile.php?id={$total}'>{$total}</a><div>";  
?>
```

It is my method, but there are plenty of ways to do it. Maybe even too many. If you want more information you can always refer to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $total=3;
  echo '<div class="idsdiv"><a href="profile.php?id=$total">'.$total.'</a><div>';
?>
```

You're quote are missing before and after the $total